# How do I find the unicode index of a given character in R?

Tags: r, string, unicode, character-encoding

So, I am working with text and want to remove among other the ' character, as part of pre-processing the text. This seems easy enough. Just print the offending character in the console, copy-paste it into the code and use regex to remove all instances of this character. However the character RStudio prints is not equal to the character in the string, meaning:

> > substr(myString, 38, 38)
>   [1] "’"
>   > substr(myString, 38, 38) == "’"
>   [1] FALSE

Where in the second line I manually copied the output of the previous line. So my question is: given a character in a specific instance of a string, how do I generate something that equals that character?

Edit: charToRaw gives e2 80 99 as output. Also:

> > rawToChar(charToRaw(substr(t, 38, 38)))
>   "â€™"
>   > rawToChar(charToRaw(substr(t, 38, 38))) == substr(t, 38, 38)
>   FALSE

Comment: can you share `myString`?

Comment: Well, when i copy the character exactly from the original text-file it was read from, I get: ’  
This is also not equal to the character in the variable. Do you know if there is a function to see the byte-value of a character?

Comment: `charToRaw` will return the bytes of a string: `charToRaw("hello")`

Comment: There is definitely something strange going on. charToRaw gives ' e2 80 99' as output. I edited the main post